# Remove iframe and prevent conflicts with libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

We have an application to make carrusel images and we are using an iframe to insert in web pages.

We want to remove the iframe, and we have all ready to work just with one div, something like this is that our users will insert in their pages:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/mycustom-carrusel.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-unique-id" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
```

The *mycustom-carrusel.min.js* has all our code minified with gulp.

Our javascript will call our API and paint all the necessary inside the div, the problem is that we are using some libraries, like jQuery and others.

We want to prevent the conflict with for example jQuery or whatever other library that could conflict with the web page of the user.

What is the best technology to implement this and prevent any possible conflict with our code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Isolation of styles and scripts from the page the widget is embedded to is exactly why `iframe` is typically used. Just keep using `iframe`.

In some future (once implemented in all popular browsers), instead of `iframe`, you could use the [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) CSS property with a value of [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset), [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial), or [`revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert), to reset all inherited styles for your widget element and its nested elements and then safely apply your own styles.

For JS libraries in general, there is probably no universal way to prevent conflicts, but specifically for jQuery, you could use [`jQuery.noConflict(true)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to free both `$` and `jQuery` variables to make it possible for other libraries (including different versions of jQuery itself) to reuse these variables, but only as long as you are able to include your jQuery version and call `jQuery.noConflict(true)` *before* the page’s own jQuery version (which is unlikely). Alternatively, just get rid of using libraries at all (libraries like jQuery are currently actually unneeded in most cases), and instead just use your own vanilla-JS script or, if you really can’t drop using a library, try to wrap the code of the library (together with your own code that uses the library) in a self-executing anonymous function to prevent variables it defines from leaking to the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have problems with the css, all my class have a custom random selector, but with JS I need something more robust... How works for example twitter?

Comment: What exactly as for Twitter?

Comment: The code you insert in a web page when you want to insert a timeline of a user for example

Comment: Could you provide a link to a page containing a working example?

Comment: Hi @Marat, sorry for the delay, here you have an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ncoLkcc5/